# Socket.IO with Python + React

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, sockets

I am making a web app and wanted to use React for the frontend and Python for the backend and Socket.IO to communicate between the two.

I tried to get a simple setup and establish a connection between the frontend and backend but I am running into issues.

Here is my barebones server implementation that I run using `gunicorn` on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

```
import socketio

# Create a Socket.IO server and WSGI application
sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='*')
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connected!', sid)
```

In React, I have the `sockets.js` file.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] },
);
```

I try to use this `socket` variable in `App`, but it does not work.

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Home } from "./Home"

import { socket } from '../services/sockets';

export default function App() {
    socket.emit("hello")

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

I see the following errors in the console.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:
```

In terms of versions, I am on `python-socketio==5.5.1` and on `"socket.io-client": "^4.4.1"`.

Would love your help on the best way to establish this connection between the backend and frontend. Let me know if you have any more questions.